# Is the difference of two percentages also a percentage?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If I have some share of a product in some sector as 2012-50%  2013-60%

If I find share change for 2013-12 then should it be 10% or 0.1?

Comment: Please suggest some tags that are related to the question

Comment: $$10\%=\frac{10}{100}=\frac1{10}=0.1$$

Comment: Not about mathematics, but differences of percentages are usually expressed in *points* or [percentage points][1].


  [1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentage_point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the shares from $2012$ to $2013$ show an increase of $10\%$, which corresponds to a net change of $$\dfrac{60\% - 50\%}{100\%} = + 0.1$$

Note that $10\% = \dfrac {10}{100} = 0.1$, so $10\%$ is equivalent to one-tenth, that is: $0.1$.

On the other hand, if we want to find the *percent change* from the rate in 2013 with respect to the rate in $2012$, then we need to divide (rate in 2013 - rate in 2012) by the (rate in 2012):

$$\dfrac{60\% - 50\%}{50\%} = \dfrac{10}{50} = +0.2 = +20\%$$

That is, the rate in 2013 shows an increase in $20\%$ with respect to the rate in $2012$.

Comment: can I represent the 10% net change as 0.1? because if we tell 0.1 change in share, is it same as 10% change?

Comment: which 1 do you think is the better way? 0.1 or 10%

Comment: Since your talking about percentages, using $10\%$ should be fine. But just note that $0.1$ is exactly the same thing as $10\%$, so either answer is correct.